# Drop all rows from a dataframe based on value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been looking this site and google for an answer to my question, but they all apply to columns.

In my data set there are a couple of cells which only contain a space, instead of NaN. So I would like to drop all the rows there this is the case. I know I can use the code below to do so per column. But how do I apply this to the entire dataframe?

`df= df[df.column != ' ']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need remove all rows with space at least in one column add [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test if all values per rows are `True`s:

```
df= df[(df != ' ').all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Works now, ill accept when it becomes available.